# Assign shifted diagonal values with np.diag

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, diagonal

I'm trying to assign values to multiple diagonals of a matrix. For example, I have this matrix:

```py
>>> u = np.zeros(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> u
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I want to assign a value to the $k$-ith diagonal above. For example, if $k=1$, I want the diagonal above the main diagonal. I tried to accomplish this by using `np.diag` like this `np.diag(u, k=1) = 1` which I want to result in the following:

```
>>> u
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The thing is this throws me a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` as this goes again Python. But `np.diag` returns a reference to the original matrix as you can see:

```py
>>> np.may_share_memory(np.diag(u, k=1), u)
True
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regardless of what it returns, python does not allow you assign to the call.  That just basic python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
u[np.eye(len(u), k=1, dtype='bool')] = 1
print(u)
```

Out:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Awesome! It should be an option to do `np.fill_diagonal(u, 1, k=1)`. Maybe I can make an issue on GitHub. What do you think?

Comment: I know. That was my first thought, too. But no `k` argument for `fill_diagonal`. I don't think that would be a priority for the developers. My solution feels like a hack, perhaps someone will post a nicer approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you are slightly misinterpreting the `diag(v,k)` as its parameters are (sub, super)-diagonal matrix from a vector `v`. To achieve your desired matrix you can do the following:

```
 u = np.zeros(25).reshape(5,-1)
 v = np.ones(5) # a vector v, a parameter in the diag(v,k=1)
 u = u + np.diag(v[:-1], 1) # k indicates the offset (negative being sub, positive being super)
 print(u)
 >>> array([[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
            [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]])
```

Now you can see the vector `v` slicing directly depending on `k` because the offset diagonals have fewer elements. This method can give any elements you want to an offset diagonal by creating a vector with the desired values and adding it to your zero matrix. Using this we can change the values of any offset diagonal. I hope this answers your questions and shows that we can do it for any numbers by creating a vector using `full((n,m),q)` or for that matter having any vector.